# Restapi GET call making website extremely slow

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, rest

I'm using React with typescript and a self-made RESTapi. I'm making a GET request on one page, and for some reason my website is extremely slow, and is sometimes even completely blocking the UI - which started happening after implementing the GET RESTapi call in the getData() and renderMultipleCards() function.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to fix it?

```
import "../css/stylesheet.css";
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image'
import Omnivores from "../images/ProductBanners/omnivoresCrop.png";
import Carnivores from "../images/ProductBanners/CarnivoreCrop.png";
import Herbivores from "../images/ProductBanners/herbivoreCrop.png";
import Small from "../images/ProductBanners/smallDinosaursCrop.png";
import Medium from "../images/ProductBanners/mediumDinosaursCrop.jpg";
import Large from "../images/ProductBanners/largeDinosCrop.png";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Card, CardDeck } from "react-bootstrap";
const ALL_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/products";
const SMALL_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/size/Small/products";
const MEDIUM_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/size/Medium/products";
const LARGE_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/size/Large/products";
const CARNIVORE_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/diet/Carnivore/products";
const HERBIVORE_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/diet/Herbivore/products";
const OMNIVORE_DINOS = "http://localhost:3000/velocishop/diet/Omnivore/products";
const ALL_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/products";
const SMALL_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/size/Small/products";
const MEDIUM_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/size/Medium/products";
const LARGE_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/size/Large/products";
const CARNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/diet/Carnivore/products";
const HERBIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/diet/Herbivore/products";
const OMNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL = "http://localhost:3005/velocishop/diet/Omnivore/products";



export default function AllProducts() {
  var header: string = "";
  var url: string = "";
  var apiUrl: string = "";
  const [dinos, setDinos] = useState<Array<any>>([]);

  const handleSetDinos = (e: any) => {
    setDinos(e);
    console.log(dinos)
  };

  const renderImageAndHeader = () => {
    url = window.location.href
    switch (url) {
      case ALL_DINOS: {
        header = "All Dinosaurs"
        apiUrl = ALL_DINOS_API_CALL
        console.log(apiUrl)
        return Omnivores
      }
      case SMALL_DINOS: {
        header = "Small Dinosaurs"
        apiUrl = SMALL_DINOS_API_CALL
        console.log(url)
        return Small
      }
      case MEDIUM_DINOS: {
        header = "Medium Dinosaurs"
        apiUrl = MEDIUM_DINOS_API_CALL
        console.log(url)
        return Medium
      }
      case LARGE_DINOS: {
        header = "Large Dinosaurs"
        apiUrl = LARGE_DINOS_API_CALL
        console.log(url)
        return Large
      }
      case CARNIVORE_DINOS: {
        header = "Carnivore Dinosaurs"
        apiUrl = CARNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL
        console.log(url)
        return Carnivores
      }
      case HERBIVORE_DINOS: {
        header = "Herbivore Dinosaurs"
        apiUrl = HERBIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL
        console.log(url)
        return Herbivores
      }
      case OMNIVORE_DINOS: {
        header = "Omnivore Dinosaurs"
        apiUrl = OMNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL
        console.log(url)
        return Omnivores
      }
    }
  }

  function getData(url: string) {
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        handleSetDinos(data)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }


  function renderMultipleCards() {
    getData(apiUrl)
    return (
      <CardDeck>
        {dinos.map((dino) => (
          <div key={dino}>
            <Card>
              
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{dino.productName}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  {dino.size},
                  {dino.diet},
                  {dino.price}
              </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
              <Button variant="primary">Add to cart</Button>
            </Card>
          </div>
        ))}
      </CardDeck>
    )
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <div className="banner-wrapper">
        <Image src={renderImageAndHeader()} fluid />
      </div>
      <div className="for-small-screen-display"><h1>{header}</h1></div>
      <div className="card-wrapper">
        {renderMultipleCards()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `getData` is an async operation (fetching data from an API). You can't call it then just map over the data on the next line. Spend a little time researching sync vs. async code in Javascript and the implications of each. On top of that, you call `renderMultipleCards()` in the function, body which calls `getData(apiUrl)`, which does an API request and then sets the state. That state change will trigger a re-render, causing `renderMultipleCards()` to be called again and the loop will start over, looping infinitely. Need to call it once when the component mounts, then render after data is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `renderMultipleCards` is issuing a side-effect of fetching data *during* the render cycle, and then updating state. This causes render looping.

You likely only need to fetch the data once when the component mounts. Use a mounting `useEffect` hook (i.e. empty dependency) to accomplish this. Remove the `getData(apiUrl)` call from `renderMultipleCards`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData(apiUrl);
}, []);
```

Since it seems your data fetching has a dependency on `apiUrl` then you should make `apiUrl` part of the component state and add it to the effect's dependency array. I suggest refactoring the component to create a map/object to "lookup" the header, api url, and image source values based on the `window.location.href` value.

```
const metaData = {
  ALL_DINOS: {
    header: "All Dinosaurs",
    apiUrl: ALL_DINOS_API_CALL,
    image: Omnivores
  },
  SMALL_DINOS: {
    header: "Small Dinosaurs",
    apiUrl: SMALL_DINOS_API_CALL,
    image: Small
  },
  MEDIUM_DINOS: {
    header: "Medium Dinosaurs",
    apiUrl: MEDIUM_DINOS_API_CALL,
    image: Medium
  },
  LARGE_DINOS: {
    header: "Large Dinosaurs",
    apiUrl: LARGE_DINOS_API_CALL,
    image: Large
  },
  CARNIVORE_DINOS: {
    header: "Carnivore Dinosaurs",
    apiUrl: CARNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL,
    image: Carnivores
  },
  HERBIVORE_DINOS: {
    header: "Herbivore Dinosaurs",
    apiUrl: HERBIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL,
    image: Herbivores
  },
  OMNIVORE_DINOS: {
    header: "Omnivore Dinosaurs",
    apiUrl: OMNIVORE_DINOS_API_CALL,
    image: Omnivores
  }
};

export default function AllProducts() {
  const [dinos, setDinos] = useState < Array < any >> [];
  const [{ apiUrl, header, image }, setMeta] = useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // get metadata object or empty object fallback
    setMeta(metaData[window.location.href] ?? {});
  }, [window.location.href]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setDinos(data)) // <-- set dinos state directly
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [apiUrl]); // <-- apiUrl state dependency

  function renderMultipleCards() {
    return (
      <CardDeck>
        {dinos.map((dino) => (
          <div key={dino}>
            <Card>
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{dino.productName}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  {dino.size},{dino.diet},{dino.price}
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
              <Button variant="primary">Add to cart</Button>
            </Card>
          </div>
        ))}
      </CardDeck>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="banner-wrapper">
        <Image src={image} fluid /> // <-- image state
      </div>
      <div className="for-small-screen-display">
        <h1>{header}</h1> // <-- header state
      </div>
      <div className="card-wrapper">{renderMultipleCards()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When I do as you suggest, I get the error "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.". Do you by any chance know why, and how I can fix it?

Comment: @ssh Ah, I see, yeah, similar issue then with `renderImageAndHeader()` updating state. Sorry for confusion, I'll take a deeper look and get an update up as soon as I can.

Comment: @ssh I have updated my answer with a more exhaustive code edit suggestion, please check the update.